# EROOR AL CONVERTIR XML a Tabla en MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql, mssql

Saludos a todos estimados colegas, actualmente estoy presentando un problema a intentar convertir un XML a tabla en mssql server, debido a la estructura sobre la cual trabaja un software en específico, el hecho es que al intentar convertir el XML en una tabla la misma me muestra dependiendo de la consulta los valores que necesito, pero cuando agrego otro nivel la consulta se rompe y me da la tabla en blanco.

Este es el modelo del XML almacenado en una columna de la base de datos.

```
  <Zones id="101">
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>RESTAURANT</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\RESTA-POSA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
       <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Mesa 1</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>Habitaciones</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\RESTA-POSA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
       <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Habitacion 1</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Habitacion 2</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
</Zones>
```

Algo Similar a este árbol.

```
Zones
--Zone
---Descrip
---Image
---Items
----Item
-----Descrip
```

Mi problema es que Después del primer Descrip toda la consulta se rompe y ya me muestra todo en blanco.

La consulta t-sql que trato de usar para esto es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = convert(xml,Zonas) FROM rtEnviroments

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT Descrip
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Zones/Zone/Descrip/Image/Items/Item/Descrip')
WITH 
(
Descrip [varchar](max) '../Descrip[3]'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

No sé qué hacer, sé que estoy recorriendo mal el XML, pero no logro como recorrer correctamente esta estructura.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien que quieres conseguir, lo ideal es convertir los nodos en tablas, el contenido del nodo es una tabla en si, no puedes anidar registros no sé si me explico, ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Zonas nvarchar(1000)

SET @Zonas = '<Zones id="101">
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>RESTAURANT</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\RESTA-POSA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
       <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Mesa 1</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>Habitaciones</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\RESTA-POSA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
       <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Habitacion 1</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>Habitacion 2</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
</Zones>'

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = convert(xml,@Zonas)


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

-- consulta cada nodo como una tabla y la vuelcas en tabla, después se trabaja con la tabla:
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Zones')
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Zones/Zone')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar el nombre del primer Descrip por ejemplo indicar Description?. Puede que no sepa extraer nodos con el mismo nombre, en cualquier caso, tal como lo veo yo cada nodo del xml es un registro anidado, como el primer Descript es como la columna que pertenece al nodo Zone, accediendo a Zone te devolverá todas las columnas, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

el XML ya lo logré recorrer anoche, el tema es que no puedo accedes a la primera descripción, por ejemplo el XML conserva esta estructura.

```
Zones
--Zone
---Descrip -- Esta descripcion me la Repite aqui! *
---Image
---Items
----Item
-----Descrip  ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip  ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip  ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
---Items
--Zone
--Zone
---Descrip -- Me Sigue Repiendo la Primera descripcion *
---Image
---Items
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
---Items
--Zone
--Zone
---Descrip -- Me Sigue Repiendo la Primera descripcion *
---Image
---Items
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
----Item
-----Descrip ----Estas Descripciones que son los hijos de las principales si las entrega correctamente
----Item
---Items
--Zone
Zones
```

Para poder recorrerlo estoy usando la siguiente consulta.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @XML = convert(xml,Zonas) FROM rtEnviroments
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
SELECT   dato.Zona
        ,dato.Descrip
        , CASE WHEN ocupe.CodMesa IS NULL THEN 'DISPONIBLE' ELSE 'OCUPADA' END ESTADO
        , case when dato.Descrip like '%(MAT)%' THEN 'MATRIMONIAL' WHEN dato.Descrip like '%(DOB)%' THEN 'DOBLE' WHEN dato.Descrip like '%(SUI)%' THEN 'SUITE' WHEN dato.Descrip like '%(TRI)%' THEN 'TRIPLE' WHEN dato.Descrip like '%(QUI)%' THEN 'QUINTUPLE' END 'TIPO'
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Zones/Zone/Items/Item/Descrip')
WITH 
(
Zona [varchar](max) '../Zones/Zone/Descrip'
,Descrip [varchar](max) '../Descrip'

) dato left join rtCustomerAccounts ocupe on dato.Descrip = ocupe.CodMesa where dato.descrip like '%HAB %' order by dato.descrip asc

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Pero aun asi no logro acceder correctamente a la primera Descripcion para que me muestre de un lado la primera descripcion asociada a la segunda descripcion.

Este es el XML Exacto.

```
<Zones id="101">
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>RESTAURANT</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\Saint\Administrativo_restaurant\Imagen_rest\RESTA-POSA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>ASDRUBAL</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>EDUVES</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>FAMILIA MUÑOZ</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>FRANCIS-FRANYE</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>GEIDY</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>JHOAN</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>JHONATTAN</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>LUIS</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>LUZMILA</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>MESA 04</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>MESA 07</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>MESA 08</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>MESA 10</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>OSMEL</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>RONNY</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>SERGIO</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>SILLA 01</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>SILLA 02</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>SILLA 03</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>SILVIA</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>SOLYSMAR</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="1">
        <Descrip>YESENIA</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
  <Zone porcent="10" price="3">
    <Descrip>HABITACIONES</Descrip>
    <Image stretch="0" transparent="0" proportional="0">C:\Saint\Administrativo_restaurant\Imagen_rest\POSADA.jpg</Image>
    <Items>
      <Item seats="2">
        <Descrip>HAB 01 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="2">
        <Descrip>HAB 02 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="2">
        <Descrip>HAB 03 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="2">
        <Descrip>HAB 04 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 05 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 06 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 07 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 08 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 09 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 10 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 11 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 12 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 13 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 14 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 15 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 16 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 17 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 18 (SUI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 19 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 20 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 21 (TRI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 22 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 23 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 24 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 25 (TRI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 26 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 27 (TRI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 28 (TRI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 29 (QUI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 30 (QUI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 31 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 32 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 33 (MAT)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 36 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 40 (TRI)</Descrip>
      </Item>
      <Item seats="4">
        <Descrip>HAB 43 (DOB)</Descrip>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Zone>
</Zones>
```